# Linux VM not serving request from client

Tags: vmware-workstation, centos-7

I have a centOS configured as a proxy server and have 2 client centOS connected to it. All these are VMs and are in VMware workstation. the server machine have 2 ethernet cards 1 for external connectivity and the other a NAT-ed adapter which is also used in client machines. When i ping the server from both client its working but When i try to send request from client to server using curl-loader like load test tool i am getting

```
received response from host with invalid source port
```

and

```
invalid legacy unicast query packet
```

messages in server machine syslog and none of the request is getting served.
Any help is much appreciated